Why am I not getting correct cursor coordinates with Windows API functions?
I am trying to capture the coordinates of the cursor in a Windows application. While the coordinate for the position (0, 0) is displayed correctly in the upper left corner, the coordinates become more and more distorted the further I move away from it, so that instead of (600, 600) only (583, 560) is displayed in the lower right corner. Here is the code I'm using

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT MainWindowProcedure(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            POINT Cursor;
            GetCursorPos(&Cursor);
            ScreenToClient(Window, &Cursor);

            char Buffer[256];
            snprintf(Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), "X: %d, Y: %d \n", Cursor.x, Cursor.y);
            OutputDebugStringA(Buffer);

        } break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        } break;
        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
        } break;
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
        WNDCLASSEXA WindowClass = {0};

        WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
        WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProcedure;
        WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        WindowClass.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

        if (RegisterClassExA(&WindowClass) != 0)
        {
            HWND Window = CreateWindowExA(0, "WindowClass", "Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 600, 600, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
            if (Window != 0)
            {

                int Running = 1;
                while (Running) {

                    MSG Message;

                    while (PeekMessageA(&Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                    {
                        if (Message.message == WM_QUIT)
                        {
                            Running = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        TranslateMessage(&Message);
                        DispatchMessageA(&Message);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}

I also tried GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_LPARAM from the Windowsx.h. The exact same problem. Does somebody have a clue, what the problem could be?

You should not be doing GetCursorPos() - get the coordinates out of the LParam argument (as you do say you've tried). You'll never get 600, 600 from a window with those dimensions as the coordinates are those of the client area, which is smaller in order to accommodate borders, and such.

You might want to use AdjustWindowRect if you want a particular client size. It will inflate the rect to the necessary size needed to handle the borders, menu, etc.

Everything appears to be working as designed. The system faithfully reports the cursor coordinates as the mouse cursor moves across the client area of the window.
The issue is one of misguided expectations. The nWidth and nHeight arguments in the call to CreateWindowExA() describe the width and height of the window, including the non-client area (borders, title bar, etc.).
The documentation entry about Application Windows has the following illustration that demonstrates how the client area is smaller than the window rectangle:

To find out where the mouse cursor is relative to the client area of a window you can call GetClientRect() to determine the extents of the client area or create a window with a specific client area size. AdjustWindowRectEx() calculates the window size for a given client size.
Bear in mind that all of this is subject to DPI virtualization. High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows covers the details.
